# Selenium, Chrome смена proxy "на лету"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Как сменить прокси в Chrome не перезагружая браузер и возможно это сделать в нем?

Comment: связанный вопрос [how do i set proxy for chrome in python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11450158/4279)